# javascript code execution time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascriptcore

I just wanna know,how I can get the execution time of my javascript code.For example I have any javascript code(loop,function etc..) I wanna know how much time takes to executing it.Or test my code how many operations it makes for example per second or minute.

Comment: Have you tried Developer tools for Chrome? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Answer (score 3):

to calculate execution time use `console.time` (dev tools):

```
console.time("test");
//execute your code here
console.timeEnd("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
var startFrom = new Date().getTime();
//measured code here
console.log(new Date().getTime() - startFrom);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using a profiling system.  If you use Google Chrome, for example, can hit ctrl-shift-i (Windows) or alt-command-i (OS X) and click on the **Profiles** tab.  You can then select the **Collect Javascript CPU Profile** radio button and then hit **start**.

You'll find a bit more information here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I know about is `Date`:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();  //Time in ms
doSomething();
var end = new Date().getTime();
console.log("Operation took "+(end-start)+" miliseconds.");
```

But I suppose every browser has it's profiler allowing you to get more info. At least in firefox, there's a profiler if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. I nevr used it, so you must try it yourself.